# inserting returned data ie7& ie8 issue with .html()

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, insert

In ie8 I am getting a strange behavior the data is not inserting.

```
$.get('events.php', createEvents);
  function createEvents(data) {
  $('#result').html($(data));
```

if I try

```
$('#result').append('<p>some html</p>');
```

this works but this does not

```
 $('#result').append($(data));
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` is your friend. You probably get a datatype you don't expect.

Comment: ReferenceError: data is not defined - how do I sort this ?

Comment: You need to do it in your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

`$.get()` tries to be smart when determining the content type of the response. Since you seem to always get HTML, use `$.ajax()` with a proper `dataType` options:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'events.php',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Then you really want to have a look at the data you receive in the callback function...

Answer (score 0):

plain old innerHtml worked. Every other browser worked ok with this so I assume rather than your code or the data it was ie8's problem. Could have been another minor bug.